# Workload of PhD in US/Europe/Canada

Tags: phd, working-time, work-life-balance

I am a Masters student applying for PhD in computer science to various universities in the US/Europe/Canada. I wanted to know about the workload in general which we will have while pursuing it in these countries.

I did a bit of research here, and found that the teaching workload is highest in the US, followed by Canada and then Europe. In the US for the first two years we will be doing coursework majorly and working in different labs to find out what we want to work on, this time is lesser in Canada and Singapore, while in Europe we straightaway start working on the problem.

Any information would be very useful, specifically in teaching and in general. Thank you

In Singapore, NUS and NTU, in Canada the University of Toronto, the University of Alberta and McGill. In the US, CMU, University of Chicago and UNiversity of Minnesota

In Europe I'm specifically looking at colleges in the UK ( like the Imperial College of London, Oxford and UCL) and Switzerland (EPFL and ETH Zurich). Answers on any other university are welcome as well.

Comment: Teaching, supervising and organizing seminars are always helping to capture more research questions. However, I don't think it is suitable for PhD students to observe research problems, it is rather helpful for senior PhD students or postdocs.

Comment: Probably each and every institution will set their own limits... Contact the institutions directly and ask.

Comment: I think one the question: what are average teaching loads in PhD programs in [short list of countries] is a reasonable question for this site?  However, the actual answer varies wildly with the university and department, so this may not be helpful for you.  The more specific and precise your question can be, the better.

Comment: I'll narrow it down as far as I can at the moment

Comment: Should I narrow it down to a couple of universities or so only?  I was actually looking for a comparison between these universities, that is too broad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can provide some information about the US, and maybe a bit of perspective.

First note that the process of doctoral education is quite different in the US and parts (at least) of Europe. I'll focus mostly on things such as CS and mathematics. It may be different in other fields.

In the US, there is a relatively low bar for acceptance into a doctoral program. An undergraduate degree is all that is normally required, though some institutions may expect more. Not only that, but a four year undergrad program in the US is a generalist degree, not a specialist one. The "major" subject is between 1/3 and 1/2 of the total coursework and not every student is much exposed to research.

Moreover, most doctoral students in the US in these fields are, in a sense, self funded, as they are employed by the university mostly as TAs (sometimes RAs). Universities with doctoral programs in math and CS, also normally teach a lot of undergrad students, which means either lots of small classes or larger classes with lots of TAs. There aren't normally enough regular faculty to teach all of the courses, so they depend on doctoral students to help.

In Europe, I suspect that the bar is higher for entry, with more courses and research experience expected. I also suspect that doctoral education there is somewhat less dependent on student teachers and assistants. In some places, doctoral students are regular employees, and may, therefore, also be teachers.

But, I think you need to expect that no matter where you are, that doctoral education is a full time endeavor. You can "have a life" with outside interests, but your full time "job" is directed toward your degree. The exception would be for someone who can do a degree part time on their own funding. These are rare. And, I think that "full time" normally means more than 40 hours per week. Most people make sacrifices in that way and require that other family members are willing to accept that. It isn't so much that it is demanded of you, though it might be, but that research isn't a regularized process. There is no way to say that in X course I will achieve Y results. Insight is precious.

Whether the "time to degree" differs depends on how you measure it. From the end of a secondary education to a doctorate is likely about the same anywhere. There are things that need to be learned and research that needs to be done and reported. Whether you count that as part of a specialized undergraduate degree, or an MS degree, or doctoral education, matters little. Since the starting point is about the same, and the end point is about the same, there are few shortcuts.

So, what is best for you, depends on where you currently are. If you have the prerequisites done for specialized research, then you want a program that will let you get to it. Otherwise you want something that will help you reach that point.

I'll note, however, that, even in the US, if you are well prepared on entry, many doctoral programs will expedite your entry into research without a lot of course preliminaries. You need to pass exams and write a dissertation. You won't, most likely, be expected to repeat courses for which you are already well prepared, though you may need a way to demonstrate your competence. You will need funding, and, as an international student, few fellowships will be open to you. So you will probably be expected to teach or TA. If you are already an experienced teacher, you may have more advanced duties than most, but (student) visa restrictions can still get in the way.

Comment: Thank you, that was very useful. US Universities take undergrads directly, but when they are considering Masters' students for admission into a PhD programme, I think they would be expecting a minimum quality of research work done, is that right?

Comment: Not necessarily, or at least not a lot. Not every US master's has much research. Some do, of course. What you need is some evidence of _preparedness_ to do research.

Comment: "In Europe, I suspect that the bar is higher for entry, with more courses and research experience expected" Many European PhDs have no courses. All coursework is wrapped up in the bachelor and master. The PhD consists only of research and teaching, as a paid employee. At least that is the case in the Netherlands.

Comment: @ElectronicToothpick A PhD student is not an employee in all European countries (France: yay, UK: nay, Spain: has been changing form model to model if I'm not mistaken). The coursework requirement also depends on the country _and_ the programme. I had formal coursework requirements in France (some of which had to be non-STEM for a CS PhD); but they weren't strictly enforced (I got my language courses to count towards it though). Some UK PhD programmes also admit students directly from Bachelors and the newer CDT programmes have obligatory, enforced coursework in the first year.

Comment: Oh, and surprisingly, I've never had a teaching obligation in France (in fact, they make a distinction between teaching PhD students and non-teaching ones in their contracts), and I've had many other colleagues that had to do no teaching. I am still actively trying to make up for the lack of teaching experience, even though I missed out on it through no fault of my own. In the UK, teaching or not depends on your contract, as well as if you'll be paid for it or not (if teaching is listed as one of the things you have to do "in return" for your grant, then it is not paid, otherwise it is)

Comment: @penelope, I think you have the basis for an answer in these comments.

Comment: Possibly, but this is mostly about (first year) courses and teaching possibilities. I'm not sure I feel confident enough to comment on the _workload_ in _top-tier universities_ OP is asking about. I'm in a mid-ranked UK university right now, and my team actually puts great value in work-life balance (we still binge for deadlines, but this was the first time ever I was told to take an "unofficial day off" after a submission). I'm not sure I can realistically extrapolate info about workload in top-tier unies, like Oxbridge for the UK and EPFL and ETH for Switzerland, based on my expirience.

Comment: @penelope, you don't need to carry the whole load. Others can fill in as well.

Comment: @penelope Please do write an answer, this information is incredibly useful, especially coming from someone who is doing a PhD first-hand, I will be applying to universities in the top tier, mid-ranked and safe ones too, I specified them as a starting point because my initial question was too broad

Answer (score 2):

I can provide an answer for the UK (Cambridge, Oxford - Doctoral Training Centres):

- It is very competitive to get in (a degree with top marks from a well known university + a flaming recommendation letters + a paper from your BSc/MSc thesis (or thesis in a top lab) would usually get you an interview).
- Once you are in you should be aware that doing a PhD (DPhil) in such
  places is way beyond a "normal" job. It is more a philosophy and you
  are basically married to your thesis project. And people do not mind putting insane working hours in as work and life merges. You will not hear a phrase like "Its 5 pm - time to go home". This is not because you can not go home (if you want to for some reason no one is going to stop you) but because you do not want to go home because you want to make the best out of the chance given to you.
- This does however not mean that you will not have any free time. Top
  places usually make sure that you have time to relax your mind and social activities are a big deal ("rowing teams" is a keyword here).
- Teaching: It depends very much on your funding - between zero and few
  hours per week (definitly not suffocating).